# short exact sequence and long exact sequence in cohomology in an abelian category ( with enough injective)

Tags: exact-sequence, abelian-categories

Good morning,

I am asking a question about the fact that a short exact sequence in an abelian category induces a long exact sequence in cohomology. 
I believe I can show this in the case, for instance, of abelian groups, as I can work with concrete elements and chase diagramm.

I read, that we can use an embedding theorem, and work as if it was the categorie of A-module, and so the proof I got is satisfying.
Anyway, I would like to know if it exists a proof showing the existence of the $\delta$-map without using elements of objects, ie using only the axioms and properties of abelian categories.
Thank you.

Comment: It seems to me that your question is not really about derived functors (even though this might be the motivation for you asking it). You might want to consider to change the title to match your question. Regarding your question, I recall reading a proof of this in Matthias Künzer's script on homological algebra, you can find it on his homepage, however it is in German. The only thing you really need is the Snake Lemma and this is proven there without reference to categories of modules.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer, is anyone there know any proof of this in the english litterature?